# WebView HTML text box blur event doesn't work

Tags: android, webview

I am working on an Android project which is loading a webpage inside a Webview component.
An important thing to mention is I have no access to the website code.

The issue is as follows.

There is a form on the website which has a text input field with a suggestion list. When a user types on the textbox, automatically a suggestion box appears and the user able to select an item from the list.

When the user clicks on the textbox, cursor focus on it and the android keyboard appears.
When the user selects an item from the suggestion list, textbox loses its focus and disappearing the cursor for milliseconds, but again textbox gets focused which means the cursor appears inside the textbox and previously hidden keyboard appear again.

Above behaviour causes for poor user-friendliness.

How can I implement to keep hidden the keyboard after the user selects a suggestion?

Given below is the code to load the web view.

```
private void loadSite(){
        siteWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.siteWebView);
        siteWebView.loadUrl(IndexURL);
        siteWebView.setWebViewClient(new SiteWebView());

        WebSettings siteWebSettings = siteWebView.getSettings();

        siteWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        siteWebSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        siteWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        siteWebSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        siteWebSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        siteWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        siteWebSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        siteWebSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        siteWebSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        siteWebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        siteWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Disabled horizontal scrolling and enabled zooming
        siteWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        siteWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        siteWebSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        siteWebView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
}
```

Comment: Please share the webView loading code and check the path on which the html file is loading.

Comment: @LAnantaPrasad I included the code snippet